# how i can declare a variable and access it inside 2 functions in python

Tags: python, function, for-loop, count, increment

In Python, I am new with python, I don't know about it , started a week ago. I want to count how many times I am executing fuction1.

````
       the_list = ["1","2","3"]

       for i in the_list:
           print(i)

           function1(i)


   def function1(the_list):
       the_list2 = ["a","b"]
       count = 0

        "''here I i am defining the count so the value is
       getting reset whever it is exiting for loop"""

        for j in the_list2:
           print(j) 
           count +=1
       print(">>",count)
       #here i wanna count how manny times we are running this print statment?


   function()```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define your counter as a global variable.  Honestly the better way to do this is to use Python Decorators and just decorate your function.  But essentially you are doing this.

```
count = 0

def example():
    global count
    count+=1

def example2():
    global count
    count+=1

example()
example2()
print(count)
```

Comment: You are overcomplicating it.  Just add the counter to the print function.

Comment: Not everyone is smart as you Sir